# Dynamically changing src attribute of video element

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to record stream returned from `getUserMedia()` using `MediaRecorder` after every 5 seconds and want to set recorded video to other video element by changing src attribute.
Below is code that I have wrote but problem is it gets played for first time when src attr is set but when I changed the src attr second time it doesn't get played.

```
const socket = io();

const $videoMedia = document.querySelector("#video-media");
const $remoteVideoMedia = document.querySelector("#remote-video-media");
let mediaStream = new MediaStream();

const init = async () => {
  const constraints = {
    audio: true,
    video: true,
  };

  mediaStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
  const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStream);
  mediaRecorder.start(5000);
  console.log(mediaStream);
  mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (e) => {
    const blob = new Blob([e.data], {
      type: "video/x-matroska;codecs=avc1,opus",
    });
    console.log(blob);
    $remoteVideoMedia.setAttribute("src", window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
  };
  $videoMedia.srcObject = mediaStream;
};

init().then(() => {
  console.log("media stream added");
});
```

I have check some stackoverflow answers regarding dynamically changing value of src attribute for video element but none of them worked for me.

Comment: What does `console.log(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob))` look like?

Comment: here "blob:http://localhost:3000/70388f65-d9f6-492c-9f38-c33dded5355c"
it works for first time also video gets played but when the code tries to assign the value of src second time it doesn't get played.

Comment: No including "blob:" I direct assign the value returned from `window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)` which is `blob:http://localhost:3000/a048ce17-dd68-4583-9b72-f6cff3c2a8d7`